# Trying to add OpenID to another account adds it to my account instead

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, moderator-abilities

As a community moderator I can change someone else's OpenID. I've tried to do it with a new OpenID, but instead of adding that ID to that user's account it added it to my account instead.

Comment: AND I can't get rid of it :(

Comment: "As a community moderator I can change someone else's openid." Are you sure?  That sounds like it'd be a massive security hole.  I would certainly hope it'd be limited to SOIS staff only.

Comment: @RBemrose the option is definitely there; it either needs to be fixed or removed.

Comment: @RBemrose: Why is that a massive security hole? You don't trust the moderators?

Comment: @josh's answer is correct. You can't change a user's OpenId; the link goes to the regular login page, where the openid is added to the logged in user (i.e. you)

Comment: @balpha in that case, it's extremely confusing that this link appears when looking at someone else's user page!

Comment: I'm not denying that; you make a good point. But you also have to admit that the following page makes it pretty clear that you're adding the openid to *your* account.

Comment: @balpha definitely - it *was* weird. I just assumed that the team hasn't bothered creating a separate UI for adding an openid to someone else's account since it's so rare (and for the record - I tried it on [this account](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/6154/the-spaminator), I wanted to do it so I could take over it to change its icon to the spam icon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly a "bug" but I agree that there's no reason for the link to appear on any user other than yourself, so.. that's how it is now, once we do another deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're talking about?

[image]

This *could* be a bug (that it's showing that link) but from looking at how it's working it doesn't appear to add an OpenID to the user.

Comment: It's either a bug that it shows the link, or it's a bug that it adds the ID to the wrong account; either way, it's wrong

Comment: @Michael: Correct.