# Recovering myopenid password

Tags: support, openid, myopenid

I have created an OpenID and using that in Stack Overflow. When I created that Id, I did not confirm the email address. So now I cannot reset my password, as I have forgotten it. Whom can I contact to reset my password and to confirm my emailId?

Comment: Also, for the future, verify your email address and write down your passwords :)

Comment: @Lasse, please don't encourage people to write their passwords down.

Comment: Is this not an issue for Myopenid instead of SO?

Comment: @Pekka - If he can't get anywhere with his provider, it kind of falls in our lap.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators don't mess with your OpenID. [Here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74458/trying-to-add-openid-to-another-account-adds-it-to-my-account-instead).

You would have to contact your OpenID provider directly to get your password re-set on their end.

It is a very good idea to have multiple OpenID users associated with your account. For instance, I use MyOpenID and Google. If MyOpenID has a problem, I can still login.

If you can't get anywhere with your provider, just create a new registered account and flag for moderator attention to request a merge with the other account. Include the old OpenID username and SO user ID in the request to help expedite things. Make sure you associate a valid and reliable e-mail with the new account as well.

The request may have to go to SOIS staff, as we (moderators) can't 100% automatically verify that you owned the account so be patient for the process to complete.

Comment: See all this time I thought that would break things :\ ... what's it take to propagate those out to the other IDs? I have a separate gravatar here (like Josh and so many others) so didn't want to mess that part up, didn't know if pushing from one to the other would cause a problem ... Anything I should be mindful of before adding new OpenIDs to my account here?

Comment: @drachenstern Adding accounts should not be an issue for you. The issue is, when a _mod_ adds one thinking they are doing it on behalf of a user, the _users's_ Open ID gets associated with the mod's account. That is clearly _not_ something that should be done :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that @TimPost!